# Recommended WinForms control for lots of read-only formatted text

Tags: winforms, controls

I`m working in a serial terminal project developed in VB.NET.

I need to display a lot of formatted (color, font styles) text data in a read-only control (the incoming serial data).
I don`t know if it's a good idea to use richtext control or a grid, or there's a better third party control?

Thanks

Comment: Now that I finish my first project with Scintilla I do not recommend this control.
First: 
If you make it read-only, it does not accept text added programmatically.
Second: I had a lot of issues because my text flow was getting to end of a line and strange chars started to appear. Like a line buffer overflow error.
Third: This project is simple not mature enough, the documentation is very rare and if you need to do something not documented you have to download the source code and study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Scintilla.NET for this sort of thing before: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

It's designed for use in text editors, but it can be made read-only, and it's pretty quick even for large quantities of text. You get efficient per-character control over colours and basic text styling, though not to the same extent as the Rich Edit control.

Negative points are that it's based on a control designed for use from C++ code, so there's not much in the way of .NET-specific documentation. And the .NET code is in C#, so it's probably best if you have a passing familiarity with that.

Comment: brone thank you very much for this response. I`ve downloaded the Scintilla and this control is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `RichTextBox` would be a good place to start since it's included and then you could upgrade to a 3rd party control if you hit any limitations (I'm assuming that cost is important).

Please note though that it can be a bit slow at colouring text depending on the method used. This article shows a supposedly (I haven't tried it) faster way of doing it:

http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/07/07/some-richtextbox-tricks.aspx